# HTML 5 pattern attribute

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

Is there a way in `<select>` list, for example, to make `onClick`  activate a JavaScript function that will show the `title` of the element just as `pattern` in HTML 5 does?

I want to do that when you click on the `<select>`, it will activate a JavaScript function that under some condition (doesn’t matter—some `if` expression) will show a sentence (that I wrote) in a bubble like place (the place that the `pattern` shows the title when something isn’t according to the pattern (`pattern` in HTML5)).

Comment: can you please explain your problem in detail...?

Comment: you like to show your message in only html right?

Comment: if you like to use dialog box then refer this one... https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: what do u mean by only html? and i dont want to use jquery, is there another way? in javascript and html only?

Comment: alert("your message");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a custom validity error on a `select` element by calling the `setCustomValidity` method, which is part of the [constraint validation API](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-constraint-validation-api) in HTML5 CR. This should cause an error to be reported, upon an attempt at submitting the form, in a manner similar to reporting `pattern` mismatches. Example:

```
<select onclick="this.setCustomValidity('Error in selection'); 
  title="Select a good option">
```

(In practice, you would probably not want to use `onclick` but `onchange`. But the question specifically mentions `onClick`.)

There are problems, though. This only sets an error condition and makes the element match the `:invalid` selector, so some error indicator may happen, but the error message is displayed only when the form data is being validated due to clicking on a submit button or something similar. In theory, you could use the `reportValidity` method to have the error shown immediately, but browsers don’t support it yet.

On Firefox, the width of the “bubble” is limited by the width of the `select` element and may become badly truncated if the longest `option` text is short. There is a simple CSS cure to that (though with a possible impact on the `select` menu appearance of course).

```
select { min-width: 150px }
```

You might also consider the following alternative, which does not affect the `select` element appearance in the normal state but may cause it to become wider when you set the custom error:

```
select:invalid { min-width: 150px }
```

There is also the problem that Firefox does not include the `title` attribute value in the bubble. A possible workaround (which may or may not be feasible, depending on context) is to omit the `title` attribute and include all the text needed into the argument that you pass to `setCustomValidity`.

A possible use case that I can imagine is a form with a `select` menu such that some options there are not allowed depending on the user’s previous choices. Then you could have

```
<select onchange="if(notAllowed(this)) setCustomValidity('Selection not allowed')" ...>
```

where `notAllowed()` is a suitable testing function that you define. However, it is probably better usability to either remove or disable options in a `select` as soon as some user’s choices make them disallowed. Admittedly, it might mean more coding work (especially since you would need to undo that if the user changes the other data so that the options should become allowed again).

Comment: if i want to try and use the reportValidity, i just have to put it instead of the setCustomValidit? and do you know in which browsers it does work? Thank you very much!

Comment: No, you would call `reportValidity` after calling `setCustomValidity`, since the latter sets the field to invalid state, so that there is validity violation to be reported. But it seems that `reportValidity` has no browser support (console logs show “undefined method” or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion Jukka's solution is superior however, its fairly trivial to do something approaching what you're asking for in JavaScript. I've created a rudimentary script and [example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fDQz/) which should be enough to get you going.

```
var SelectBoxTip = {
    init : function(){
        SelectBoxTip.createTip();
        SelectBoxTip.addListeners();
    },
    addListeners : function(){
        var selects = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
        for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++){
            var zis = selects[i];
            if(zis.getAttribute('title')){//only if it has a title
                zis.addEventListener("focus", SelectBoxTip.showTip, false);
                zis.addEventListener("blur", SelectBoxTip.hideTip, false);
            }
        }
    },
    createTip : function(){
        tip = document.createElement("div");
        tip.id = "tip";
        tip.style.position = "absolute";
        tip.style.bottom = "100%";
        tip.style.left = "0";
        tip.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        document.body.appendChild(tip);
    },
    showTip : function(e){
        this.parentNode.appendChild(tip);
        tip.innerHTML=this.title;   
        tip.style.display="block";
    },
    hideTip : function(e){
        tip.style.display="none";
    }
};
SelectBoxTip.init();
```

Comment: Thank you very much!, but i want to try Jakka's answer first